# Extract texture from glb file

Tags: unity, textures

How do you extract the texture from a glb file in Unity?

I'm not sure if it is from `_MainTex` or `BaseColorTexUV`?

[image: Image from Gyazo]

Comment: Why don't you just try both and see what works. If you have possible solutions, try them, you should only come to Stack Exchange when you cant find any answers to your problem.